# probability that at least 8 cars arrived in between 12:03pm-12:07pm given that 10 cars arrived during 12:00pm-1:00pm

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

Assume that vehicles arrive at a toll plaza according to a Poisson process. The average inter-arrival time between vehicles is $10$ minutes. One third of the vehicles are cars, and two thirds are trucks. (And the event that a vehicle is a car is independent of the arrival process.) The lunch hour is. Find:

$$P(\text{at least 8 cars arrived in [12:03, 12:07]} \mid 10 \text{ cars arrived during the lunch hour})$$

The answer is $$\sum^{10}_{i=8} {10 \choose i}\left(\frac{4}{60}\right)^i \left(\frac{56}{60}\right)^{10-i}$$ I know that the poisson distribution is the limiting case of a binomial distribution when number of trials is very large but here our n is small. Can anyone give me some hint as to why it is binomial in this example?

Comment: what other method are you going to use beside binomial??

Answer (score 0):

we can divide the hour in 1 min intervals in 60 sections

So every car has 60 options it can choose from

n(S) = $60^{10}$

Choosing 'i' car out of 10 = $\binom{10}{i}$

these 'i' cars only have 4 options available between  [12:03, 12:07]

Total cases = $4^i$

The rest of the cars '10-i' has 56 options available

= $(56)^{10-i}$

Total no of ways to get exactly 'i' cars in interval [12:03, 12:07]

=$\binom{10}{i}$ $4^i$$(56)^{10-i}$

Probability = $\frac{\binom{10}{i} 4^i(56)^{10-i}}{60^{10}}$ =${10 \choose i}\left(\frac{4}{60}\right)^i \left(\frac{56}{60}\right)^{10-i}$